# angularjs filter remote content

Tags: angularjs, playframework-2.1

I'm getting a html with angular content from a service, the content is something like that

```
<div>{{ @event.dateBegin | stringToDate }}</div>
```

the service is something like

```
$scope.setContext = function() {
   $http.get(service).success(function(response) {
          $scope.content = response;
    });
```

the content div is

```
<div class="span9" ng-bind-html-unsafe="content"></div>
```

and for result I got the correct html formmed div, but the part {{ }} dosen't work,I agree angular-sanitize but dosen't work too

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$interpolate service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate).  Example in the docs:

```
var $interpolate = ...; // injected
var exp = $interpolate('Hello {{name}}!');
expect(exp({name:'Angular'}).toEqual('Hello Angular!');
```

So, in your specific example, inside your success callback:

```
var exp = $interpolate(response);
$scope.content = exp(event);
```

As a recommendation, I would just pass back the data, not the HTML, if you can help it and keep all of the templates in your angular application.

Comment: I trying  use a component like this            <td><a><span tooltip-popup-delay='1000' tooltip='appears with delay'>@event.name</span></a></td> , but dosen't work

Comment: Well, first off you need your variable `event.name` in the {{}}s so that the value can be injected in the template. Second, @event is not a valid java script variable: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: @event is a variable in playframwork, I'm refer to the tooltip ui component in angular bootstratp